# Login Script with Function Won't Authenticate User

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, login-script

I have created a script that uses a function called "authenticateuser", when I enter the wrong user name and password the program correctly works, but when I enter the correct credentials it still returns failed. Tried moving things around but could not find the solution. Are things not in the right place or am I missing some final code?

```
loggedin = False
wrongcount = 0

def authenticateuser(theusername, thepassword):
    theusername = "homerjsimpson"
    thepassword = "marge"


def main():

    username = ""
    password = ""   


while loggedin == False and wrongcount < 5:
    username = input("Please enter username: ")
    password = input("Please enter password: ")
    if password == authenticateuser and username == authenticateuser:
        loggedin = True
    else:
        print("Authentication Failed")
        wrongcount = wrongcount + 1
        loggedin = False

if(loggedin == True):
    print("Welcome to the program!")
else:
    print("Locked Out")

main()
```

Comment: What does the `authenticateuser(..)` function do, and what does this statement do: `if password == authenticateuser and username == authenticateuser:`

Comment: From my very novice understanding, if the code was run without the function it would look like `if password == thepassword and username == theusername`. But because I created the `authenticateuser` function I replaced them to call the function into use. Not sure if that clears it up?

Comment: Where are you calling the function?  What does the function return?

Comment: I thought by adding it in the second `if` statement I was calling the function. The function should be returning `loggedin = true` and printing `Welcome to the program!` when I type in the credentials correctly. But for some reason the script keeps skipping past that and going to `authentication failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authenticateuser` must do something with the input parameters, and return `True` if the username/passord match, otherwise it must return False.

We can write it many different ways, e.g. version 1:

```
def authenticateuser(theusername, thepassword):
    if theusername == "homerjsimpson" and thepassword == "marge":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

version 2 (better):

```
def authenticateuser(theusername, thepassword):
    return theusername == "homerjsimpson" and thepassword == "marge"
```

version 3 (even better):

```
def authenticateuser(theusername, thepassword):
    authentication_db = {
        # username       # password
        'homerjsimpson': 'marge',
    }
    return authentication_db.get(theusername) == thepassword
```

Usually when we're logging someone in we'll need to keep track of their logged in status.  Let's create a simple class (`Session` for this purpose):

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, username=None, loggedin=False):
        self.username = username
        self.loggedin = loggedin
```

The login function can now ask for username and password, and call `authenticateuser` to see if they are correct. If they're not correct we increment the wrongcount counter.

In either case we return a Session containing the username and whether the user is logged in:

```
def login():
    loggedin = False
    wrongcount = 0

    while not loggedin:
        username = input("Please enter username: ")
        password = input("Please enter password: ")

        if authenticateuser(username, password):
            return Session(username, True)

        wrongcount += 1
        if wrongcount > 5:
            return Session(username, False)
```

Now main can call `login()` and get back a `session` object. This object can be checked for `.loggedin` and the appropriate message can be printed. Since we've recorded the username we can also personalize the message:

```
def main():
    session = login()
    if session.loggedin:
        print("Welcome to the program!", session.username)
    else:
        print(session.username, "you've been locked out!")


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the password and username are a function, which obviously they will not be. I believe you actually want `authenticateuser` to return a dictionary containing `theusername` and `thepassword`. Something like this:

```
def authenticate_user(username, password):
    return {"username": username, "password": password}
```

...

```
credentials = authenticate_user("homerjsimpson", "marge")

while logged_in == False and wrong_count < 5:
    username = input("Please enter username: ")
    password = input("Please enter password: ")
    if password == credentials["password"] and username == credentials["username"]:
        logged_in = True
    else:
        print("Authentication Failed")
        wrong_count = wrong_count + 1
        loggedin = False
```

(as a side note, you should use `_` to separate words in variable and function names)

Comment: I have yet to be taught to separate variables like that, is there a specific reason or is that just a logical thing for reading the code easier?

Comment: It's just python convention so that other programmers can read your code better and you can read other programmers' code better.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't properly calling authenticateuser.  Something like this would do what you intend:

```
loggedin = False
wrongcount = 0

def authenticateuser(theusername, thepassword):
    if theusername == "homerjsimpson" and thepassword == "marge":
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():

    username = ""
    password = ""


while loggedin == False and wrongcount < 5:
    username = input("Please enter username: ")
    password = input("Please enter password: ")
    if authenticateuser(username, password):
        loggedin = True
    else:
        print("Authentication Failed")
        wrongcount = wrongcount + 1
        loggedin = False

if(loggedin == True):
    print("Welcome to the program!")
else:
    print("Locked Out")

main()
```

Edit: Also you main call isn't doing anything.  python code evaluates line by line so your "main" loop is actually where you do the "while loggedin == False".  By the time you call the function main, your program has basically finished everything and the main just sets the username and password to empty string but does nothing further with those values